# Search folder and get files

Tags: c#, .net

I am having one folder containing all .jpg files. Now I am having some part of file name. I want all files whose name contains that part from that folder.
thank you in advance...

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383574(v=vs.110).aspx) to do this. And just give it the search pattern.